# Active Subscription Missing from Azure Portal

Tags: powershell, azure, azureportal

I'm no longer able to see the Azure Subscription associated with my "Visual Studio Enterprise – MPN" offer from the Azure portal. I am able to see the subscription from PowerShell, and the multiple resources I have running in the subscription are still operating as expected. I recently renamed the subscription from "Visual Studio Enterprise – MPN" to "MSDN". I suspect the rename is related, but I'm not sure how to resolve the issue. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: It turns out that I can see the resources in my MSDN subscription. They appear under my Default Directory, but I remember having to select the "Visual Studio Enterprise - MPN" directory or subscription before. Any ideas on why this would have changed when I renamed the subscription from "Visual Studio Enterprise - MPN" to "MSDN"?

Comment: This question is unfortunately off-topic. That said: Make sure you have the correct directory and subscription chosen (all of this is in the portal's subscription filter).

Comment: Thanks @DavidMakogon but the subscription does not appear in the global subscription filter.

Answer (score 2):

What David's comment was trying to say is if you are seeing subscription in PowerShell and not in Azure Portal it's likely been filtered.

[image]

Make sure you have all checked or at least the subscription you are missing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The subscription does not appear in my global subscription filter.